# Is it safe to call getsockopt() and read()/write() simultaneity in different threads?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking

Suppose I have two threads:

- Thread 1 keeps reading from or writing into sockets via read()/write().
- Thread 2 sleeps for several seconds and then calls getsockopt() to get tcp_info from socket.

Is it safe to do so in linux box?

I know it would be better to use epoll or select in this case, but I just want to know whether the above approach is safe....

Thanks.

Comment: It is safe, but unpredictable, but really, why? Do you really need two threads per socket?

Comment: well, I don't like it either. But this is legacy code, written by someone else.